# How to solve an error about drawcircle in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

In the following code, that is for draw a circle on an image, an error occurred. I try to solve it but I can't find the problem.

```
figure('color', [1 1 1]);
clf;
imshow(inputVol(:,:,85),[]);
drawcircle([blobSlice(ind,2),blobSlice(ind,1)],round(sqrt(3)*blobSlice(ind,4)),50,'-','g', 1); % Error
```

For Instance:

```
I = imread('Img.jpg');
% blobSlice(ind,2) =  179;
% blobSlice(ind,1) = 206;
% round(sqrt(3)*blobSlice(ind,4)) = 9;
imshow(I,[]);
drawcircle(gca, [179, 206], 9, 500, '-', 'g', 1); % Error is here.
```

And the error is:

```
Error using images.roi.internal.ROI/parseInputs
ROI parent must be a valid Axes object.

Error in images.roi.Circle

Error in drawcircle (line 165)
h = images.roi.Circle(varargin{:});

Error in tumor2dVis (line 18)
    drawcircle([blobSlice(ind,2),blobSlice(ind,1)],round(sqrt(3)*blobSlice(ind,4)),500,'-','g', 1);

Error in Blob3D_Detection (line 38)
tumor2dVis(volume_image, 85, nonMaxOutput, 1);
```

So, How to solve the error about the line of drawcircle?

Comment: As per the documentation, the first input to `drawcircle` should be an `axes` object referencing in which plot you want to draw the circle. This is what the error says too. In your code, this is not the first input you are giving. We can not help more without a [mcve]

Comment: @Ander Biguri: Ok

Comment: If you explain what the values mean, I will update teh answer with working code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### [For MATLAB 2018b](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/drawcircle.html)

In your code, add the current axes, if that is where you want to plot the circle:

```
figure('color', [1 1 1]);clf;
imshow(inputVol(:,:,85),[]);

% Get current axis (gca):
ax=gca;
% add them to the function. 
drawcircle(ax,...);
```

An example would be:

```
drawcircle(gca,'Center',[206,179],'Radius',9,'StripeColor','g');
```

### For other MATLABs

`drawcircle` does not seem to exist, unless you are using some toolbox function.

Comment: I have checked it, but: `Error using images.roi.Circle/set
Invalid parameter/value pair arguments. and Error in images.roi.internal.ROI/parseInputs`

Comment: There is no error in the function of `viscircles(gca,[179,206], 9, 'Color','g');`, but I couldn't find the reason of `drawcircle`'s error?

Comment: @eli have you read the documentation? https://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/drawcircle.html You are not callign the fucntion right

Comment: @eli yes, because the arguments are not correct, they are not the way the fucntion is called, as clearly state in the documentation

Comment: @eli, the first argument of `drawcircle` must be **Axes in which to draw circles, specified as a handle object returned by gca or axes.** So you should first build a ax like Ander did.

Comment: @eli I am sorry you disagree with MATLAB documentation, I can not help you more if that is the case.

Comment: @eli maybe you are referring to [this](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/49853-drawcircle-center-radius-varargin), but it's not an official matlab function.

Comment: @Bebs: No, I have used the function of Matlab. [link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/drawcircle.html)

Comment: @eli, in that case you don't use it correctly. Look at the link you sent, the first argument is `ax`.

Comment: @Bebs: I have explained in the above: After using the `ax`, an error occurred:` Error using images.roi.Circle/set Invalid parameter/value pair arguments. and Error in images.roi.internal.ROI/parseInputs`

Comment: this `drawcircle(gca, [179, 206], 9, 500, '-', 'g', 1)` is incorrect, `gca` is not defined, and the other arguments don't make sense for this function.

Comment: @Bebs: Ok, I'm trying to find it.